# TAP expression for entropy

Tags: mp.mathematical-physics, entropy, statistical-physics, ising-model

This paper by Barton and Cocco: http://www.phys.ens.fr/~cocco/Art/articlejstat.pdf 
claims on page 17 (Formula (30)) an expression for the "high-temperature" entropy of an Ising model, given its moments.

They go on to say this can be derived the same way the usual TAP equations are derived -- however the references they provide all provide expressions only for the free energy. (And it's not clear to me how to extract information about the entropy only from this.)

Could someone enlighten me if this is easy to see?